# Maven build How to invoke child pom plugin phases using the maven command line

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jacoco, parent-pom

i'm not a maven expert. we are trying to integrate the jacoco plugin using jacoco ant in our multi maven module . I am following the procedure given in the below link

https://dzone.com/articles/jacoco-maven-multi-module

The procedure says to add few plugins in the sub-module and call few modules class files to integrate the files .When i added the plugin in my child pom in the sub-module, how to invoke it .

Initially i am using the below command line to .

goals = ' mv clean install'

I have added the submodule in my parent and the child moduke is getting called but the plugins are not getting invoked .

Comment: For JaCoco you don't need Ant you can do via jacoco-maven-plugin. The linked article is 7 years old...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise - We tried that earlier and yes there are few confutions .

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise - Even after explicitly providing the jacoco version as 0.7.8 in the dependecy, it is taking the 0.7.5 version . Also how to call the goals like  report & report-aggregate .